# Mongodb find comparing diffrent elements from the same array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array with say two elements, want to compare element[0]and element[1], return true if element[0].code== element[1].code

```
"SourceArray" : [ 
        {
            "source" : "Acetone",
            "code" : "90915"
        }, 
        {
            "source" : "Ketone",
            "code" : "90915"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#expr) with aggregation expressions, like:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      "$SourceArray.0.code",
      "$SourceArray.1.code"
    ]
  }
})
```